# Java JPA Criteria Builder: Check nested, nullable value

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity that refers to another entity:

```
class Person {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
  Company employer;
}

class Company {
  String employeeBenefits;
}
```

In the example, `employeeBenefits` can have all kinds of values including `"No benefits"`.

Importantly, a person's `employer` can be `null`.
I want to use the Criteria Builder to construct a Specification that checks if a person **has no employer OR has an employer with "No benefits"**.

My approach was:

```
criteriaBuilder.or(
  criteriaBuilder.isNull(model.get("employer")),
  criteriaBuilder.equal(model.get("employer").get("employeeBenefits"), "No benefits")
);
```

This does not work; persons with a `null` employer are not found. I think the reason is that during evaluation of the second expression, the `.get("employeeBenefits")` throws a NullPointerException, which silently leads to the person being excluded from the result set.

I have also tried the inverse `criteriaBuilder.notEqual(model.get("employer").get("employeeBenefits"), "No benefits").not()` but that does not work either.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

model.get("employer") forces an inner join, which filters out nulls. You will need something more along the lines of a left outer join from model->Employer that you can reuse for the null and employeeBenifits value checks akin to JPQL query `select p from Person p left join p.employer e where ( e is null OR e.employeeBenefits = "No benefits")`.

You can do this in criteria queries using something more like:

```
Join<Person, Company> employer = model.join("employer", JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaBuilder.or(
  criteriaBuilder.isNull(employer),
  criteriaBuilder.equal(employer.get("employeeBenefits"), "No benefits")
);
```